# Disposing a background worker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker

Is it necessary to dispose off the Background Worker after I have done the processing work inside the DoWork event, or being a managed object this will automatically get disposed eventually?

Previously, I was performing some functions inside the `timer_elapsed` i.e to perform a task every thirty seconds.
Now, I am doing the same processing inside the BackGround Worker's `DoWork` event. How do I loop this bgWorker event to be performed after every 30 seconds (say) `bgworker.RunWorkerAsync();`

If I put this `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` indie `timer_elapsed`, how do I dispose it after every timer elapse?

Comment: If you are going to need it again then why disposing it ?

Comment: why do you want to use a background worker? A timer seems more appropriate to trigger an operation based on an interval

Comment: @Aybe: My concern was that the timer should run unlimited times i.e after every 30 second or so until the `windows service` that I am using this in closes. So, where do I dispose this?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Here's my previous post from which I decided to use `Background worker` instead of the main thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793278/implementing-a-waiting-routine-inside-a-timer-elapsed-event

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to Dispose of a BackGroundWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542326/proper-way-to-dispose-of-a-backgroundworker)

Comment: After reading the linked question: you're better off with a timer and a little state-tracking logic: Does-it-run-now, Did-it-run-at-last-tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to dispose off the Background Worker after ...

No. The BackgroundWorker does implement the IDisposable interface but only as a blanket feature inherited from Component. It serves no purpose.

> If I put this `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` in `timer_elapsed`

Doubtful if you should do that at all. But if you do, just create a new Backgroundworker each time.

A Backgroundworker is a relatively 'light' object, it holds no resources. The thread is borrowed from the ThreadPool.

If you are a stickler for principal, you may call Dispose() on the old one before creating a new one. But it won't make much difference.

Comment: Creating a new thread for each background `timer_elapsed` looked like  an overkill to me, but I think it's fine if the resources held are very low.

Comment: As Henk mentioned, you aren't actually creating threads (usually), just borrowing them from a thread pool.

Comment: HenkHolterman, For anyone that sees this. Your comment is probably unintentionally misleading. The backgroundworker runs operations on another thread but only when called.